# Is it legal to multiply both sides of a linear equation with a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read in my book that the cancellation laws do *not* hold for matrix multiplication. That is if $AB=AC$, then it is *not* true in general that $B=C$.

However I keep seeing examples where people left/right multiply both sides of an equation like this:
\begin{align*}
AB &= IX\\
A^{-1}AB &= A^{-1}IX\\
(A^{-1}A)B &= (A^{-1}I)X\\
B &= A^{-1}X\\
\end{align*}
Shouldn't that be incorrect?

Comment: $A^{-1}$ has to exist

Comment: @Henry In that particular example $A$ is invertible.

Comment: If $A^{-1}$ exists, then $AB=AC$ _does_ imply $B=C$. If $A$ is not invertible (or if we don't know), then $AB=AC$ does _not_ imply $B=C$.

Comment: The reason that $AB = AC$ doesn't generally imply $B = C$ is that, if we're speaking *generally*, then we don't know that $A$ is invertible.  And if $A$ isn't invertible then we may have $AB = AC$ but $B \ne C$.

Comment: Addressing the question in the title: Certainly the converse is true: if $B = C$ then $AB = AC$, i.e. you can always multiply both sides of an equation by a matrix and it will remain true. In your example it's legal to multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ as long as $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: If $A$ is not square  then $A^{-1}$ does not exist.  (Similarly if $A$ is square with zero determinant.)  So it is unlike real numbers, where only division by $0$ is an issue

Comment: Since the OP doesn't say it: I hope that all matrices are $n \times n$ and all have full rank. Is that the case?

Comment: @Andreas $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix while $B$ is $n \times p$ matrix.

Comment: @Bungo So I can left/right multiply both sides of any linear equation with any matrix as long as it keeps the equation defined?

Comment: @razzak Yes, suppose we have $B = C$. Then $B - C = 0$, i.e. $B-C$ is another name for zero. Multiplying any matrix (of compatible dimensions) by zero gives us zero, hence if we multiply by $A$ we get $A(B-C) = 0$. This means that $AB - AC = 0$, so $AB = AC$.

Comment: @razzak Going off of Bungo's comment, consider a simple arithmetic example where $2\cdot 2 = 4$. Since these two quantities are equal, I can do the same thing to both sides (say apply a function $f$) and still have equality, i.e. $f(2\cdot 2) = f(4)$. Consider the case where $f$ is the function that says to multiply its argument by $3$, then we have $2\cdot 2 = 4 \implies f(2\cdot 2) = f(4) \implies 3(2\cdot 2) = 3\cdot 4$.